# No default authentication scheme has been set

Tags: c#, oauth, .net-core, identityserver4

I am in the process of upgrading from IdentityServer4 1.x to IdentityServer4 2.0 which also means that i have upgraded the to .Net core 2.0 I am aware that there are a lot of breaking changes with this upgrade I have done it once before but for some reason I am stuck on this error.

> warn: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
>         No default authentication scheme has been set. Setting a default scheme is required.
>   warn: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
>         No default authentication scheme has been set. Setting a default scheme is required.

The error appears in `Configure` after i call `app.UseIdentityServer();`

Configure method:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration);
            else
                loggerFactory.AddConsoleJson(Configuration);

            InitializeDatabase(app);

            // Stops microsoft from overwriting claim types to their proprietary ones
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowCredentials()
            );

            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

**ConfigureServices method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var settingsSetup = Configuration.GetSection("Settings").Get<Settings>();
        settingsSetup.XenaConnectionUrl = Configuration["XenaPath"];
        services.AddSingleton(settingsSetup);

        var idsConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("XenaIdentityConnection");
        var xenaConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("XenaConnection");
        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;


        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(builder =>
            builder.UseSqlServer(xenaConnectionString));

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.TryAddScoped<UserManager, UserManager>();
        services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager, SignInManager>();
        services.TryAddSingleton(new XenaClient(Configuration));
        services.AddTransient<Services.IClaimsService, XenaClaimsService>();
        services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

        // Sms service setup
        services.Configure<SmsOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("SmsOptions"));
        services.AddTransient<ISMSService, SMSService>();
        services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, PasswordValidator>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(LoadCertificate())
            // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(idsConnectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(idsConnectionString,
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

            })
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Supporter", policy => policy.RequireClaim("supporter"));
        });
    }
```

I am setting DefaultAuthenticateScheme  so i cant really figure out what the problem is.  I have resorted to digging around in the source code and it seams to have something to do with the validation I am obviously not adding something but i cant figure out what it is [source](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/a28ac7ae6d86eb40d2865734fe85b06f0ab44f26/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/IdentityServerApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L83)

Comment: And what is `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`?

Comment: here you go   @evk https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityconstants?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.  All the following does is initialise it.  It doesnt actually add an authentication type.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    });
```

The project I was using as reference had the following

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            })
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.AccessType = "offline";
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:GoogleClientId").Value;
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:GoogleClientSecret").Value;
            });
```

But my current project does not need google login at this time so i just removed that part.   Which caused it to fail becouse no authecation type had been added.

I just removed the `AddAuthentication` part and everything is working now.